# Sass: using control directive on a calc() variable

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to achieve this on a `div`:

**Calculate and set its `margin-left` but make sure the value is positive.**

So I come up with the following:

```
.div {
    $margin-left: calc(50vw - #{$div-width});
    @if $margin-left > 0 {
        margin-left: $margin-left;
    } @else {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

But the SASS compiler gives: `Undefined operation: "calc(50vw - 603px) gt 0`

Is there a correct way to achieve this?

Comment: `calc()` is a function for calculate CSS property values, you have to use in a css propiety but `$margin-left` variable is a number, isn't it? I'm not sure what you want to archieve, this code line has not sense if `$margin-left:` is a numeric value:  `$margin-left: calc(50vw - #{$div-width});`

Comment: I think I finally understand what you want to do but you can't use `calc()` in SASS to do a mathematical operations, `calc()` is used in CSS propieties and calculate in execution time. You can do a mathematical operations but you can't mix units.

Comment: I've also come to a realization that realtime calculation and condition checking is out of the capability of sass / css. Sass is to be compiled into css so it doesn't get a hold of the execution value, thus not being able to perform condition checking on an undefined variable. (Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can´t change the value of a property depending on the value of another in realtime with CSS, yo need javascript to do that